# React Ag-grid after you press ENTER in cell edit, move cursor down to next row (like Excel)

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want the cursor to move down to next row after an edit is completed and ENTER is pressed, like it happens in Excel.

The code for a basic grid is bellow

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { AgGridColumn, AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";

import "ag-grid-enterprise";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";

const App = () => {
  const [gridApi, setGridApi] = useState(null);
  const [gridColumnApi, setGridColumnApi] = useState(null);

  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([
    { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
    { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
    { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 },
  ]);

  function onGridReady(params) {
    setGridApi(params.api);
    setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi);
  }

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
      <AgGridReact onGridReady={onGridReady} rowData={rowData}>
        <AgGridColumn field="make" editable={true} />
        <AgGridColumn field="model" editable={true} />
        <AgGridColumn field="price" editable={true} />
      </AgGridReact>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have also attached a Plunker link for the same code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Qmzz0tMQtWrDFTtH

How do I move cursor to next row when editing is completed by pressing ENTER

Comment: Not the same, But may be this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46608047/use-enter-key-to-navigate-to-cell-below-in-ag-grid

Also take a look at this docs. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/cell-editing/#enter-key-down

Comment: @AppajiChintimi The second link you sent me is perfect and exactly the solution I was looking for. Do you want to write an answer, so I can upvote it and mark it as the answer?

Comment: You can write your approach yourself and mark it. I didn't look deeper in that. May be it helps some others. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ag-grid had added this functionality as can be seen at this link: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/cell-editing/#enter-key-navigation

The following property need to be set to true on the Grid `enterMovesDown` and `enterMovesDownAfterEdit`

Working Code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { AgGridColumn, AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';

import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

const App = () => {
  const [gridApi, setGridApi] = useState(null);
  const [gridColumnApi, setGridColumnApi] = useState(null);

  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 },
  ]);

  function onGridReady(params) {
    setGridApi(params.api);
    setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi);
  }

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
      <AgGridReact
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
        rowData={rowData}
        enterMovesDown={true}
        enterMovesDownAfterEdit={true}
      >
        <AgGridColumn field="make" editable={true} />
        <AgGridColumn field="model" editable={true} />
        <AgGridColumn field="price" editable={true} />
      </AgGridReact>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Working Plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/y2rgFQc1cc5dzOdq